# Pass a 2D array to function

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, arduino

I have a 2D array

```
byte sensor_AND_1[2][NUM_OF_MAX_SENSORS] = { { 0 }, { 0 } }; 
byte sensor_AND_2[2][NUM_OF_MAX_SENSORS] = { { 0 }, { 0 } };
```

and a function where I need to pass the array to

```
if (is_valid_sensor_id_AND(sensor_AND_1,ID)) {  /*do something*/ }
else if (is_valid_sensor_id_AND(sensor_AND_2,ID)) {  /*do something*/ }
```

What is the correct declaration to pass the whole array to the function?

```
bool is_valid_sensor_id_AND(byte *arr, byte sensor_id)
    {
       for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_OF_MAX_SENSORS; i++) {
          if (arr[0][i] == sensor_id) {
             arr[1][i] = 1;
             if (isset_counter(arr[1], NUM_OF_MAX_SENSORS)==isset_counter(arr[0], NUM_OF_MAX_SENSORS)) { triggered(sensor_id);  memset(arr[1], 0, NUM_OF_MAX_SENSORS); }
             return true;
          }
       }
       return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer how to pass it to the function:
bool is_valid_sensor_id_AND(byte arr[][], byte sensor_id)